# USB2.0 to (Wireless or Bluetooth ) to USB2.0

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

I am after a piece of advice, I have a Labjack U6 which is a USB2.0 device I want to use wirelessly. unfortunately using a wireless router and accessing it using TCP is not an option.

is there any hardware out there that I can use, has anyone configured a set-up like this.

I have to say again as I know the first 2 things that come to mind which are the Raspberry and using wireless router then accessing it using TCP ... both are no options in my case.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't have a problem, I am after advice if anyone heard or used such hardware, all the hardware available online are based on accessing the USB over a wireless network but that is not possible in my case, I need hardware that I plug the labjack to and another hardware that I plug into a computer then  the 2 hardware communicate wirelessly simulating  the labjack being directly plugged in the laptop